# SoP Multiclassing and talents gained

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spheres-of-power

We are using [Spheres of Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/) (SoP) 3pp for pathfinder for the first time in our group and theres something I need to clarify.

I was considering multiclassing in SoP to gain more talents at the cost of some [class](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/spheres-of-power-classes-class-options/) features, and under casting read

> Note: All casters gain 2 bonus talents and may select a casting tradition the first time they gain the casting class feature.

All the classes say this. Which makes me wonder if it behaves more like the save bonus for being a good save under the unchained rules for fractional bonuses. If its a good save you only gain that +2 once. The other possibility is that each time you take a class with this feature you get those sweet two bonus talents.

So which is it, does each class grant those bonus talents, or does only the first class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You only gain bonus talents once

[Magic Talents](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/#Magic_Talents) says:

> **Magic Talents**
>
> **As a caster gains levels, they gain magic talents**. Magic talents, like feats, may be spent to allow a caster to gain new powers and abilities.
>
> The number of magic talents a caster gain differs between classes, but all **characters gain two bonus magic talents the first time they gain a level in a casting class**, regardless of which class is chosen. (...)

So every time your *caster level* increases, you may gain a new talent (depending on the class). For some classes, that means one talent per class level, for others it is a bit slower. For instance, the [Thaumaturge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/spheres-of-power-classes-class-options/thaumaturge/) says:

The [Casting](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/spheres-of-power-classes-class-options/thaumaturge#TOC-Casting) class feature enforces this and say that you only gain those bonus talents once, when you first obtain this class feature.

> A thaumaturge may combine spheres and talents to create magical effects. A thaumaturge is considered a High-Caster. He may use either Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma as his casting ability modifier and must make this choice at 1st level. Once made, this choice cannot be changed. (Note: All casters gain 2 bonus talents and may select a casting tradition the first time they gain the casting class feature.)

This means that the first time you pick a class that has the **Casting** class feature, you gain two bonus talents because of the *Casting* class feature, and whatever additional magic talents the class gives you. These magic talents (and not the *bonus talents*) will be granted when multiclassing into this class.

If you take a look at the [Hedgewitch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/spheres-of-power-classes-class-options/hedgewitch/) table, you will notice that she only gains 2 talents, because she starts with a caster level 0. But the number is listed in parenthesis, because it only affects those characters who are taking the *Casting* class feature for the first time, for everybody else (multiclassers) they gain 0 magic talents at level 1.

[image: Hedgewitch talents]

On the other hand, the [Incanter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/spheres-of-power-classes-class-options/incanter/) is the opposite, they gain two bonus talents for obtaining the *Casting* class feature for the first time, and two talents for taking the first level on the class, for a total of 4 talents if this is your first class, and two talents if you are multiclassing into it.

[image: Incanter talents]

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I was hoping to earn a few extra talents by multiclassing into the other high caster classes. Might still be worth it if the class itself grants access to any spheres, but I believe that only happens when they are mid or low casting classes.

Answer (score 3):

No, you only get the bonus once. "Casting" in spheres works like BAB, and when you first gain "Casting" as a class feature you get 2 baseline talents and a caster level of 1.

Comment: Backing this answer up with quotations from the book would improve it.

Comment: Comparing it to BAB seems to cause the opposite reaction, since BAB from different classes do stack.